# Setting defaultValue after the Select is rendered is not doing anything

Tags: react-select

I am using [React-Select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select), where the options come from the server (not hardcoded client-side).

After getting the result back from the server, the options are correctly populated in the Select, but the **defaultValue is ignored**.

A simplified example:

```
var fruits = [];
var defaultFruit = null;

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fruits = [{value: 1, label: 'Apple'}, {value: 2, label: 'Orange'}],
        defaultFruit = {value: 2, label: 'Orange'}  // this doesn't do anything
    }, 1000);
}, []);

return (
    <Select name='fruit' options={fruits} defaultValue={defaultFruit} />
);
```

Am I missing something?
Is there a way to set the value dynamically?

**SOLUTION:**

We've found a solution! For our case, we simply show "Loading..." at first, and only render the form after we get all the options.

Answer (score 1):

You should give `defaultFruit = {value: 2, label: 'Orange'}`. It should be one of object from array.If you don't know what the label of 2 is going to be(as it is retrieved from server), you can do `fruits.filter(fruit=> fruit.value===2)` and get that object and set it as defaultFruit.

Answer (score 1):

As Vinayak Shenoy said in his answer: Your `defaultValue` should be of type `object` with the default `value` and `label` attributes (can be changed by the `getOptionValue` and `getOptionLabel` props).

But the prop `defaultValue` is only used to set a value on initial render and keep the `Select` component uncontrolled. If you want to control the value, you should consider using the `value` and `onChange` props.

Comment: Thanks Rallen and Vinayak, I actually tried the whole object as well and it didn't work. How do you use `value` and `onChange`? Doesn't setting `value` make it read-only?

Comment: Setting `value` alone makes it read-only, but setting `value` and `onChange` makes it [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). `value` is used to show the correct option which you selected. The `onChange` prop is used in this case to set the value to state when selecting an option.